# Shiny: perform operations prior to output

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to figure out how to take the input values, perform various operations/calculations, and then outputting the results of those operations as both a plot and a text.

Here's an example to illustrate what I'm trying to get at:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mu", "Mean",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 100,
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("sigma", "Standard deviation", 
                  min = 0,
                  max = 100,
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("n", "Number of observations", 
                  min = 3,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 1000)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("output_plot"),
      textOutput("output_text")
    )
  )
)
```

Using the input parameters, I want to generate a vector `x` of random, normally distributed numbers and plot a histogram. This works fine:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$output_plot <- renderPlot({
    x <- rnorm(input$n, input$mu, input$sigma)
    plot(hist(x))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In addition to this, I want to print out the values of the mean and standard deviation of `x` as a text below the plot. If I only wanted the text, this would work:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$output_text <- renderText({
    x <- rnorm(input$n, input$mu, input$sigma)
    paste("Observed mean = ", round(mean(x), 3), ". Observed standard deviation = ", round(sd(x), 3), ".", sep = "")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**My question is, how can I generate `x` before outputting the plot and the text? I want the result to look like this:**

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nMDB.jpg)

**I don't want to generate one `x` for the plot and another for the text. I want the text to describe the mean and SD of the same `x` that is shown on the plot.**

The following does not work because reactive values can't be accessed outside of a reactive consumer:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  x <- rnorm(input$n, input$mu, input$sigma)
  
  output$output_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(hist(x))
  })
  
  output$output_text <- renderText({
    paste("Observed mean = ", round(mean(x), 3), ". Observed standard deviation = ", round(sd(x), 3), ".", sep = "")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. You just need to pass `x` to a `reactive` value. Then `reactive` values are called with parentheses.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mu", "Mean",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 100,
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("sigma", "Standard deviation", 
                  min = 0,
                  max = 100,
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("n", "Number of observations", 
                  min = 3,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 1000)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("output_plot"),
      textOutput("output_text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  x <- reactive({
    rnorm(input$n, input$mu, input$sigma)
  })
  
  output$output_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(hist(x()))
  })
  
  output$output_text <- renderText({
    paste("Observed mean = ", round(mean(x()), 3), ". Observed standard deviation = ", round(sd(x()), 3), ".", sep = "")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Follow-up question: what must I do if I want to perform operations using ```x()```, e.g., creating a new variable ```y <- 2 * x()``` from it, and then outputting both ```x()``` and ```y```? I realise that that you could simply multiply the rnorm() by 2 to double the values. What I really need to know, however, is how to perform several subsequent operations/calculations after having defined ```x()```.

Comment: You're welcome. You should pass `y` to a `reactive` component as well. However, I highly suggest that you take a look to the Shiny tutorial, as `reactive` values and `observe` are the fundamentals of Shiny. All of your questions are answered in this tuto : https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/#get-started